# Somar hora à uma data e hora com PHP

Tags: php

Bom dia.

Fiz uma vasta pesquisa antes de perguntar, e não achei a resposta.

```
$row['data_saida'] = "2019-06-20";
$row['hora_saida'] = "08:35:02";
```

Essas duas strings vem do banco de dados, retornando a data e a hora separada (como mostrado acima), mas, gostaria de gerar uma previsão com base em outra string, que retorna do banco de dados. Ou seja:

```
$row['data_saida'] = "2019-06-20";
$row['hora_saida'] = "08:35:02";
$row['tempo_viagem'] = "02:30:02";
```

Gostaria de somar 02:30:02 com 2019-06-20 08:35:02, para obter a previsão de chegada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode efetuar essa operação com a classe [Datetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) em conjunto com o [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```php
$row['data_saida'] = "2019-06-20";
$row['hora_saida'] = "08:35:02";
$row['tempo_viagem'] = "02:30:02";

$saida = sprintf('%s %s', $row['data_saida'], $row['hora_saida']);

$data  = new DateTime($saida);
$data->add(new DateInterval("P0000-00-00T{$row['tempo_viagem']}"));

$chegada = $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Chegada com data pt-BR
//$chegada = $data->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');

echo $chegada;
```

Veja este [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pe6a-1ufc) (Clique no botão `RUN F9`)

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou muito. :D

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar `strtotime()` com a string da data e hora seguido do intervalo que se quer adicionar. Ou seja, para adicionar hora, minuto e segundo teria que seguir a data e hora com `'+X hours +Y minutes +Z seconds'`. Para fazer isso pode-se manipular a string de duração que vem do banco como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$data = '2019-06-20';
$hora = '08:35:02';
$duracao = '02:30:02';

$data_hora= $data.' '.$hora ; 
$duracao = vsprintf(" +%d hours +%d minutes +%d seconds", explode(':', $duracao)); 

print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($data_hora.$duracao));
```

Veja funcionando:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6207ff0ca1897f5c1443be549c923548020e22a6

Comment: Perfeito meu nobre. Obrigado! :D